# ruby - assignment for greps return value in if statement

Tags: ruby, regex

How to capture greps return value in an if statement for use inside block ?

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "white"]

if color = colors.grep(/^b/)                # Would be nice to capture the color blue
  puts "Found #{color.first}."              # with the regex, and pass it down to block
else
  puts "Did not find the first color."
end
```

How could we express this differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if (found = colors.grep(/^b/)).empty?
  puts "Did not find the first color."
else
  puts "Found #{found.first}."
end
```

to capture the array and check if it is empty in one go. If you only want `found.first` then I'd go with Jakub's.

Comment: I took your hint and realized that this is a bit pointless :) It's time for bed I guess.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Not necessarily pointless, sometimes it is good to be playful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that sure what you're trying to do. But if you want `color` to be the string `"blue"` in the if condition and if nothing found trigger the else condition you could try this:

```
colors = ["red", "blue", "white"]

if color = colors.grep(/b/).first 
  puts "Found #{color}."
else
  puts "Did not find the first color."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked "how could we express this differently", here's another option.

```
matches = colors.select{ |c| c.start_with? "b"}
```

This will give you an array of matching colors (those that start with the letter "b"). Then you can do the following:

```
if matches.empty?
  puts "Did not find the first color."
else
  puts "Found #{matches.first}."
end
```